# Simplify my JQuery Code

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to simplify my code but I don't know how to do it correctly. As you can see below, my function declaration is the same for all 3 but yet, I do it for each.  It seems like I should be able to do something about it before they become too many, but I'm not so sure how to do this.

```
function idone() {
  $('#id1').on('click', function () {
    var newclass = $(".f1").attr("class");
    var oldclass = $("#photo").attr("class");
    $("#photo").fadeOut(function() {
      $("#photo").removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass).fadeIn('slow');
    });
  });
}

function idtwo() {
  $('#id2').on('click', function () {
    var newclass = $(".f2").attr("class");
    var oldclass = $("#photo").attr("class");
    $("#photo").fadeOut(function() {
      $("#photo").removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass).fadeIn('slow');
    });
  });
}

function idthree() {
  $('#id3').on('click', function () {
    var newclass = $(".f3").attr("class");
    var oldclass = $("#photo").attr("class");
    $("#photo").fadeOut(function() {
      $("#photo").removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass).fadeIn('slow');
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You should really redo your formatting of the question. It is unreadable in this state.

Comment: @Khan: Thanks for formatting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with ids, add a class on the elements as well:

```
<div class="divs" id="id1"></div>
<div class="divs" id="id2"></div>
```

and add id on your `f1` class elements as well,supposing they are span:

```
<span class="fid1"></span>
```

and then write jquery like this:

```
$('.divs').on('click', function () {
    var newclass = $('.f'+this.id).attr("class");
    var oldclass = $("#photo").attr("class");
    $("#photo").fadeOut(function() {
      $("#photo").removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass).fadeIn('slow');
    });
  });
```

Comment: While my answer would solve the existing problem, this is a better general solution.

Comment: If you click on `id1` newclass will be `$(".f1").attr("class")` class. But when you click on `id2` newclass shoulb be `$(".f2").attr("class")` class. In your case it will be `$(".f1").attr("class")`

Comment: @Adam your answer is also not bad..:)

Comment: It works. Thanks! I'm a little surprised though because id1 matches to f1 and id2 matches to f2.  How do you make this work conceptually when under var newclass you've assigned f1 to it?

Comment: it will be fid1 not f1

Comment: Oh okay, made the mistake on my code but still worked somehow. Let me try again.

Answer (score 2):

```
function id(number) {
  $('#id' + number).on('click', function () {
    var newclass = $(".f" + number).attr("class");
    var oldclass = $("#photo").attr("class");
    $("#photo").fadeOut(function() {
      $("#photo").removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass).fadeIn('slow');
    });
  });
}
```

Then call it with `id(number);`

Answer (score 0):

Here what you could do :

```
$('[id^=id]').on('click', function () {
    var classToToggle = $(".f"+this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g,'')).attr("class") + ' ' + $("#photo").attr("class");
    $("#photo").fadeOut(function() {
        $("#photo").toggleClass(classToToggle).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```